# Using GIT Server(Windows), Not able to Clone back in GIT Server

Tags: windows, git

I am running a Git Windows server. I am trying to access files locally on a Windows machine. I successfully cloned the bare repo from remote to local, but when I try to push a locally created committ, the new files do not show up on the remote server. There is no error message.

I created a bare repo on a remote server:

```
/path/demo.git
```

I cloned successfully locally with this command:

```
git clone ssh://username@IP:/path/demo.git
```

Please tell me how to push commits from the local repository to the remote repository.

Comment: It is a bare repo on the remote? What files do you expect to see changed? The objects database? As long as the push went fine, if you tried cloning or fetched on another repo, you should be able to see the branch moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `git clone` you automatically get `origin` as a remote referencing the path to the repository you cloned.

You can ensure that you push implicitly to the same remote branch through configuration:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Then create some commits and run `git push`.